# Passing Parameters from Main Report to Sub Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

Here is an example of what my tablix/matrix looks like and some examples of what should happen.  I have the parameters in the second report setup to accept  values and in the main report I have just selected the field it should pass.  Since it’s a matrix and grouped, I would think if you clicked a sub total row it would know what values relate to that row.

[image]

Following examples,which define what should happen:

1.When i click on cell B3(USA) it will pass Locations name i.e USA and Customer name i.e ABC   as a parameter to sub report.

2).When i click on cell B5 i.e Sub total, it will send both locations i.e. USA,Dubai and customer name i.e.abc as a parameter to Sub Report.

3).When i click on cell B10 i.e Grand Total, it will send all  Customer names with there respective locations as a parameters to the sub report.

Thank You

Comment: what if you click on B4?

Comment: then it should pass Locations name i.e dubai and Customer name i.e ABC as a parameter to sub report.

Comment: This is tagged both `ssrs-2008` and `ssrs-2008-r2` - which specific version is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it. For the Subtotal link, pass "ALL" for the Location Parameter and `=Fields!.Customer.Value` for the Customer Parameter. For the Grand Total link, pass "ALL" for both Parameters. Then update your Sub-Report Query `Where` clause:

```
Where
    (Customer = @Customer or @Customer = 'ALL')
    and (Location = @Location or @Location = 'ALL')
```

This will return all Customer/Location records when the respective Parameters are set to 'ALL'.

Let me know if you need any more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,how can i identify with SSRS that, whether cell B4 contain location value "USA" or "Dubai",so that i can pass that value to the subreport.

Comment: Pass the `=Fields!Location.Value` (or whatever your Field Name is for Location) as the Location parameter and it will pass USA when user clicks USA and it will pass Dubai when user clicks Dubai.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve exactly what you want for your examples 2 and 3 using SSRS alone.

I would derive new columns in the Dataset to hold the concatenated parameter strings you want to pass.  For your example 2, this column might be called Customer_Locations and hold a value of "USA|Dubai".  I would pass that value to a multi-valued parameter in the sub report, using the SSRS Split function in the Subreport Parameter definition.  Its important that the chosen delimiter doesn't appear in the possible Location values.

The same value would repeat in each row of the Dataset, for all the rows for that Customer.

For example 3, I would add 2 further columns e.g. Customer_Locations_Grand_Total = "USA|Dubai" and Customers_Grand_Total = "ABC|CDE".  These same values would repeat for all rows.